# Serial connection of isolated DC/DC supplies

Tags: power-supply, serial, isolated

I need isolated 60VDC and I am struggling to get one that can provide enough current (2A is needed). It seems to me serial connection of 4 supplies that deliver 15VDC can be a solution. What can be possible problems, what passive components would you use to make it more stable? I am considering this supply https://www.tracopower.com/int/model/ten-40-2423e.
Thanks!
Walt

Comment: If you can avoid a PCB-mount requirement (and use a line-powered chassis-mounted supply), then your options will open up.  Go to 48VDC, and you would get even more options.  60V is a bit of an odd-duck.  Indicating the use in industry may help us with your search.

Comment: The specific model you suggested only has a 1⅓ A output though at 30 V (±15 V). The TEN 40-2413E model will provide 2⅔ A at 15 V, giving a margin over your requirement.

Comment: You should easily find isolated +/-30V supplies with suitable current rating which would avoid the complexity.

Comment: Best option is to find 60 V or +-30 as @user_1818839 suggests. If you do run them in series, please add a Schottky diode across each output to prevent one going into OCP, hiccup, fail outright, start faster or similar, and the other one back feeding the fist

Answer (score 0):

If you use TEN 40-2423E you add complexity, because you must connect two of them in parallel and these groups in series to get 60 V / 2.666 A. They have dual output, but these outputs are not independent.

Four single output converters like URB2415LD-30WR3 in series are much simpler. A short circuit across such a chain can revert the polarity of a module if it delivers slightly less power than others. So connect protection Schottky diodes 3 A rated parallel to each module output in reverse direction.